Getting RemoteCertificateValidationCallback Exception While trying to Run .NET Aspire App
I'm trying to run the .NET Aspire Starter App in Visual Studio on a Windows 10 machine. My coworkers seem to be able to run it just fine without making any changes to the template. I, on the other hand, keep getting the following exception:
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
Here is the dotnet info about my machine:
enter image description here
Here is the full stack trace of the exception:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_ListClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](String group, String version, String plural, Nullable`1 allowWatchBookmarks, String continueParameter, String fieldSelector, String labelSelector, Nullable`1 limit, String resourceVersion, String resourceVersionMatch, Nullable`1 timeoutSeconds, Nullable`1 watch, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.ListClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(String group, String version, String plural, Nullable`1 allowWatchBookmarks, String continueParameter, String fieldSelector, String labelSelector, Nullable`1 limit, String resourceVersion, String resourceVersionMatch, Nullable`1 timeoutSeconds, Nullable`1 watch, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.WatcherExt.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<<MakeStreamReaderCreator>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at k8s.Watcher`1.<>c.<CreateWatchEventEnumerator>b__21_1[TR](Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at k8s.Watcher`1.CreateWatchEventEnumerator(Func`1 streamReaderCreator, Action`1 onError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
   at k8s.Watcher`1.CreateWatchEventEnumerator(Func`1 streamReaderCreator, Action`1 onError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 216
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 216
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_1`1.<<WatchResourceChanges>b__10>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 334
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_1`1.<<WatchResourceChanges>b__10>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 334
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Polly.ResiliencePipeline.<>c.<<ExecuteAsync>b__3_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Polly.Outcome`1.GetResultOrRethrow()
   at Polly.ResiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.<<WatchResourceChanges>g__WatchKubernetesResourceAsync|3>d`1.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 332
Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor: Critical: Watch task over Kubernetes Executable resources terminated unexpectedly. Check to ensure dcpd process is running.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_ListClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](String group, String version, String plural, Nullable`1 allowWatchBookmarks, String continueParameter, String fieldSelector, String labelSelector, Nullable`1 limit, String resourceVersion, String resourceVersionMatch, Nullable`1 timeoutSeconds, Nullable`1 watch, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.ListClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(String group, String version, String plural, Nullable`1 allowWatchBookmarks, String continueParameter, String fieldSelector, String labelSelector, Nullable`1 limit, String resourceVersion, String resourceVersionMatch, Nullable`1 timeoutSeconds, Nullable`1 watch, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.WatcherExt.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<<MakeStreamReaderCreator>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at k8s.Watcher`1.<>c.<CreateWatchEventEnumerator>b__21_1[TR](Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at k8s.Watcher`1.CreateWatchEventEnumerator(Func`1 streamReaderCreator, Action`1 onError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
   at k8s.Watcher`1.CreateWatchEventEnumerator(Func`1 streamReaderCreator, Action`1 onError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 216
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 216
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_1`1.<<WatchResourceChanges>b__10>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 334
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_1`1.<<WatchResourceChanges>b__10>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 334
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Polly.ResiliencePipeline.<>c.<<ExecuteAsync>b__3_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Polly.Outcome`1.GetResultOrRethrow()
   at Polly.ResiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.<<WatchResourceChanges>g__WatchKubernetesResourceAsync|3>d`1.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 332
Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor: Critical: Watch task over Kubernetes Container resources terminated unexpectedly. Check to ensure dcpd process is running.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_ListClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](String group, String version, String plural, Nullable`1 allowWatchBookmarks, String continueParameter, String fieldSelector, String labelSelector, Nullable`1 limit, String resourceVersion, String resourceVersionMatch, Nullable`1 timeoutSeconds, Nullable`1 watch, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.ListClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(String group, String version, String plural, Nullable`1 allowWatchBookmarks, String continueParameter, String fieldSelector, String labelSelector, Nullable`1 limit, String resourceVersion, String resourceVersionMatch, Nullable`1 timeoutSeconds, Nullable`1 watch, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.WatcherExt.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<<MakeStreamReaderCreator>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at k8s.Watcher`1.<>c.<CreateWatchEventEnumerator>b__21_1[TR](Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at k8s.Watcher`1.CreateWatchEventEnumerator(Func`1 streamReaderCreator, Action`1 onError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
   at k8s.Watcher`1.CreateWatchEventEnumerator(Func`1 streamReaderCreator, Action`1 onError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 216
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 216
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_1`1.<<WatchResourceChanges>b__10>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 334
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_1`1.<<WatchResourceChanges>b__10>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 334
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Polly.ResiliencePipeline.<>c.<<ExecuteAsync>b__3_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Polly.Outcome`1.GetResultOrRethrow()
   at Polly.ResiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.<<WatchResourceChanges>g__WatchKubernetesResourceAsync|3>d`1.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 332
Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor: Critical: Watch task over Kubernetes Service resources terminated unexpectedly. Check to ensure dcpd process is running.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_ListClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](String group, String version, String plural, Nullable`1 allowWatchBookmarks, String continueParameter, String fieldSelector, String labelSelector, Nullable`1 limit, String resourceVersion, String resourceVersionMatch, Nullable`1 timeoutSeconds, Nullable`1 watch, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.ListClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(String group, String version, String plural, Nullable`1 allowWatchBookmarks, String continueParameter, String fieldSelector, String labelSelector, Nullable`1 limit, String resourceVersion, String resourceVersionMatch, Nullable`1 timeoutSeconds, Nullable`1 watch, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.WatcherExt.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<<MakeStreamReaderCreator>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at k8s.Watcher`1.<>c.<CreateWatchEventEnumerator>b__21_1[TR](Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at k8s.Watcher`1.CreateWatchEventEnumerator(Func`1 streamReaderCreator, Action`1 onError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
   at k8s.Watcher`1.CreateWatchEventEnumerator(Func`1 streamReaderCreator, Action`1 onError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 216
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 216
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.WatchAsync[T](String namespaceParameter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_1`1.<<WatchResourceChanges>b__10>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 334
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_1`1.<<WatchResourceChanges>b__10>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 334
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Polly.ResiliencePipeline.<>c.<<ExecuteAsync>b__3_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Polly.Outcome`1.GetResultOrRethrow()
   at Polly.ResiliencePipeline.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.<<WatchResourceChanges>g__WatchKubernetesResourceAsync|3>d`1.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 332
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (7568) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host: Error: Hosting failed to start

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_CreateClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](Object body, String group, String version, String plural, String dryRun, String fieldManager, String fieldValidation, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.CreateClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(Object body, String group, String version, String plural, String dryRun, String fieldManager, String fieldValidation, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.<>c__DisplayClass16_0`1.<<CreateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 105
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 308
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 315
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.CreateResourcesAsync[RT](CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 1740
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.CreateServicesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 818
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.RunApplicationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 132
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.DcpHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/DcpHostService.cs:line 70
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (26744) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
One or more errors occurred.

The program '[25684] AspireApp2.AppHost.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

The program '[25684] AspireApp2.AppHost.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).`
I have used dotnet dev-certs https --trust --check to verify that the dev certificate is trusted.
I have used dotnet workload update to make sure I have the latest version of Aspire (8.2.2).
